# Confusing Type Mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I can't figure this out.  It works in a simple test workbook but I get a runtime error '13' type mismatch when I attempt to use it in my larger workbook.  Thoughts?  any help is appreciated.

```
Sub ExpandRows()
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    dat = rng

    ' Loop thru your data, starting at the last row
    For i = UBound(dat, 1) To 1 Step -1
        ' If Quantity > 1
        If dat(i, 1) > 1 Then
            ' Insert rows to make space
            Set rw = rng.Rows(i).EntireRow
            rw.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dat(i, 1) - 1).Insert
            ' copy row data down
            rw.Copy rw.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dat(i, 1) - 1)
            ' set Quantity to 1
            rw.Cells(1, 1).Resize(dat(i, 1), 1) = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `1` Which line gives you the error? `2` What is the value of "i" at the time of error? `3` What is the value of "rw.Address" at the time of error `4` And since you are using "UsedRange" which is highly unreliable, what is the value of "rng.Address"?

Comment: What do you want to do if the range is composed of 1 cell only?

Comment: dat(i, 1) may not be a number. So type mismatch in Resize(dat(i, 1) - 1).

Answer (score 0):

I tested in Excel 2007, dat(i, 1) may not be a number. So type mismatch in Resize(dat(i, 1) - 1).

You should try this, with IsNumeric() checking:

```
Sub ExpandRows()
  Dim dat As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  Dim rw As Range
  Dim rng As Range

  Dim varVal

  Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  dat = rng

  ' Loop thru your data, starting at the last row
  For i = UBound(dat, 1) To 1 Step -1
    ' If Quantity > 1
    varVal = dat(i, 1)
    If (IsNumeric(varVal)) Then
      If (varVal > 1) Then
        ' Insert rows to make space
         Set rw = rng.Rows(i).EntireRow
         rw.Offset(1, 0).Resize(varVal - 1).Insert
         ' copy row data down
         rw.Copy rw.Offset(1, 0).Resize(varVal - 1)
         ' set Quantity to 1
         rw.Cells(1, 1).Resize(varVal, 1) = 1
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```